# Branding SharePoint online

Tags: branding

Where I can find resources for branding a SharePoint online site (public one).
I found a master.page but I need some guidance before I start.
Thank's

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [good link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh298214) to some MSDN information on SharePoint Online branding.  It's much the same as on premise, customizing the master page to organize the structure and using CSS to affect the styling.  [Here](http://sharepointexperience.com/csschart/csschart.html) is a helpful CSS reference chart for 2010.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to the response from @PirateEric

Also if you're looking to roll your own master page I suggest that you use the [Starter Master Pages](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex

Comment: It's about the public site of the SharePoint online from Office 365. It's a different type of master page. when I try a starter master page it gives a lot of errors